# An extension of Löb's theorem

Tags: logic

This question is an extension question of previous one.

link:
[Löb's theorem and provability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338225/lobs-theorem-and-provability)

Now, there is three sentences, P, Q and R.

sort-of-says, they are like following.

> P: P, Q and R is provable all.
>
> Q: P, Q and R is provable all.
>
> R: P, Q and R is provable all.

By previous approach, by Löb's theorem, P,Q,R is provable all.

Now expand this story to many sentences.

P(1) : P(1), P(2).... P(n) is provable all

p(2) : P(1), P(2).... P(n) is provable all

....

p(n) : P(1), P(2).... P(n) is provable all

By previous approach, by Löb's theorem, P(i) is provable from i=1 to i=n.

> My question: Is this story valid when n goes infinite?

It means,

> P(1) : P(1), P(2)......P(i)......  is provable for all i
>
> p(2) : P(1), P(2)......P(i)......  is provable for all i
>
> ....
>
> p(i) : P(1), P(2)......P(i)......  is provable for all i
>
> .....

By previous approach, by Löb's theorem,  is P(i) provable for all i ?